# simple-peerでp2p通信しようとしたらice-pwdパラメータに謎に空白文字が入る

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, p2p

環境説明：
サーバー（？）側：Google App Script
クライアント側：html (html, JavaScript, css) (多分GASにちょっといじられてから渡されてる)

自作ゲームで[simple-peer](https://github.com/feross/simple-peer)を使ってP2P通信を行っているのですが、
通信を始める前のsignalを交換するときに２回に一回くらいこのようなエラーが出ます。

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set remote offer sdp: Failed to apply the description for m= section with mid='0': Invalid ICE parameters: ICE pwd must contain only alphanumeric characters, '+', and '/'.
```

「pwd must contain only alphanumeric characters...」の「pwd」部分が「uflag」の場合もあります。

とりあえずエラー通りにエラー発生時にICE-pwdとICE-uflagの中身を見たところ、
**文字列の中に半角スペースが入っていました。**

質問：

1. エラーの原因はこれのせいでしょうか。
2. もしこれのせいなら、これはバグでしょうか。
3. もしこれのせいなら、これの解決策はあるのでしょうか。

一応、signalを交換するときにやっている処理を説明します。

clientA:１．signalをsimple-peerのeventから取得。
clientA:２．signalをJSON.stringifyで文字列化する。
clientA:３．signalをfetchのgetでgasに送信。
clientA:４．gasに着いたら、JSON.parseをする
clientA:５．gasのpropertyServiceから連想配列を取得し、JSON.parseする。
clientA:６．５の連想配列にパースされたsignalを収納し、JSON.stringifyする。
clientA:７．gasのpropertyServiceに代入する。
clientB:８．fetchのgetでgasにリクエストを送る。
clientB:９．gasはpropertyServiceから、clientAが保存したsignalを取得してmimetype:JSONで返す。
clientB:１０．取得したclientAのsignalをJSON.parseしsimple-peerのsignalメソッドで設定する。
clientB:１１．clientBのsignalをclientAと同じ方法（同じ関数を使ってる）でgasに送信。
clientB:１２．clientAがclientBがclientAのsignalを入手したのと同じ方法で取得して設定。（同じ関数を使ってる）
ー本当だったら、ここで通信が始まるはず。ー
・個人的にはバグかJSONに変換しすぎてなんかなったのかなと思っています。

追記：
処理過程(上のurlを参照)で、signalを取得した時点では空白は混入していませんでした。
JSONかfetchかpropertyServiceで何かが起きたと思います。

追記２：
"+"が" "に変化していました！

追記3
URIで+と は同じだと教えてもらいました。
fetchのgetで"+"が" "に変化したんだと思います。

Comment: 解決しました。
URIで+と は同じだと教えてもらいました。
fetchのgetで"+"が" "に変化したんだと思います。

Comment: 解決に至った情報はコメント欄や質問に追記してしまうのではなく、ぜひ個別の回答として投稿してみてください。